# Using the Object class in Java

Tags: object, stack

I understand that declaring variables of type Object or passing an Object variable as a parameter in a method is so that we can pass any object type e.g. Integer or String or an array. I just wanted to ask if we can also pass primitive data types or cast to integer primitive types too?

For example if I have a class Stack which allows us to push and pop objects of type Object, then i can use this class for Integer objects BUT can i use it for a primitive type int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, because Java will "auto-box" your primitive type. In other words, if you pass an `int` to your method, it will first get converted to an `Integer`, then that `Integer` will be passed as an argument to your method.

[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) gives more details about how it works.

Comment: will it work the other way round though? if my parameter is of type Object, can i pass a variable of type int?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking: if you have a method `public void method(Object o)` you can call it on an int: `method(1)`.

Comment: Inversely, if your pop method returns an Integer: `public Integer pop()`, you can unbox it to an int: `int result = pop();`